# How to obtain a list of all currently minimized windows?

Tags: linux, kde, window

I need a list of all currently minimized windows in the order they were minimized.

I have a mouse gesture (wipe down) assigned to minimize the current window. And I want to assign another gesture (wipe up) to "unminimize" the formerly minimized window(s).

How could this be achieved?

(in Linux/Debian/KDE)

Further Explanation: The wonderful Mouse-Gesture-App Easystroke has a built-in function for that, but ATM it mistakes the autohiding panel in KDE for a window. And therefore the "Unminimize"-gesture sometimes brings up the panel instead of the last minimized window.

What I tried so far is a very clumsy shell-script, which takes too long to execute and does not even give the right order of the windows:

1. Get a list of all open windows with `wmctrl -l`.
2. Filter out all entries which are on all desktops, i.e. docks etc. via the second column (needs to not equal `-1`).
3. Filter out all entries which are maximized windows via `xprop -id ${i} | grep -F 'window state: Iconic'`.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Are you planning to write code for doing this, or are you asking whether KDE can do it for you? Do you actually want at all windows, or do you only need the last minimized window? Do you want a list, as in a textual list? I don't get it.

Comment: Sorry for expressing not clearly!  
I want a list of all minimized windows written in a file, so I can use the file in a shell script to extract the last entry, maximize the corresponding window and finally delete the last entry.